# About Angular Error in ngDoCheck

Tags: angular

I make this angular program in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) which can help you get the detail of the program.
[program _URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcj-view-content) .

I want to make a table component with the select all function.
But It throw error in chrome develop tool when I output the selected item in angular ngDocheck method.

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'. Current value: ''.
```

Comment: Please add the essential parts to the question directly instead of only linking to external resources. What error do you get?

Comment: You open the chrome develop tool then you can see the error which in the 
method ngDocheck of tmpl.component.ts 。

Comment: you need to share more detail in question body!
Add your codes, what do you want to achieve and what error do you get. It's not possible to answer your question in current format.

Comment: This still isn't showing the error in your question. Why would anybody bother opening your link if there is no indication what the question is about.

Comment: Please don't be lazy. Post something here)

Comment: You can see all the code in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcj-view-content .